# SQL: return 2 possible values after THEN in CASE/WHEN

Tags: sql, case

I have a html select with 3 values (X, Y, Z) and I need to return data according a column value. But according to the selection, I want to filter with several different values.
For the moment, I have

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM database
WHERE "program" =
        CASE selection
     WHEN 'X' THEN 'tata'
     WHEN 'Y' THEN 'toto' OR 'titi'
     WHEN 'Z' THEN 'tutu'
  END
```

but it does'nt work. When Y is selected, I want to filter data like that

```
 WHERE "program" = 'toto' OR "program" = 'titi'
```

Have you any solution? Thanks

Comment: Use AND/OR instead of CASE in the WHERE clause.

Comment: BTW, 'database' is a really bad table name. A database typically consists of many tables and several users etc.

Comment: You should tag your RDBMS

Comment: You're not just trying to return two values, you're also magically changing the logic of the where clause to cover multiple conditions - this is not what CASE is for, which is for returning a *scalar value*, not a partial expression tree. As jarlh says, just write out your conditions separating everything with simple AND and ORs.

Comment: @jarlh 'database' is not the real name, it's just for stackoverflow

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT *` indicates your table has duplicate rows. Correct?

Comment: Actually no, I copy/paste from another request and forgot to remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the `case` expression, use regular `AND`/`OR` instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tablename
WHERE selection = 'X' and "program" = 'tata'
   OR selection = 'Y' and "program" in ('toto', 'titi')
   OR selection = 'Z' and "program" = 'tutu'
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Sometimes no need to think for complicated requests